# Mysql logs select but not update statements

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find out what update query a 3rd party web app is running on a mysql v5.6 database. I thought I would be able to see this in the general.log file, but nothing useful is being printed.

With logging turned on, this is all I see when I update something using the web interface.

```
171120 16:17:59     2 Query     BEGIN
                    2 Query     COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */                   
1020172 Query   /* PID: 113227; URI: /ajax/customer/change_status.json.is_blocked.1.is_exported.0.prov_term_date..perm_term_date..restore_date..lift_suspension_date..tz_name.Europe.2FPrague.i_customer.256.generate_invoice.0.bill_status.O.csrf_token.<token>; User: <myusername>; IP: <myIP>; Realm: admin; Script: /usr/sbin/httpd; Statement: GetACLPermissionsBulk; */

SELECT p.i_acl as i_acl,
       p.access_type as access_type, p.mode as mode,
       p.object as object, p.attribute as attribute
FROM Access_Levels acl, Access_Levels_Permissions p
WHERE acl.i_acl = p.i_acl
ORDER BY acl.i_acl

1020172 Query   /* PID: 113227; URI: /ajax/customer/change_status.json.is_blocked.1.is_exported.0.prov_term_date..perm_term_date..restore_date..lift_suspension_date..tz_name.Europe.2FPrague.i_customer.256.generate_invoice.0.bill_status.O.csrf_token.<token>; User: <my username>; IP: <my IP>; Realm: admin; Script: /usr/sbin/httpd; Statement: GetAllAccessLevelsBulk; */
```

The field I updated is "blocked", so the commend on the 1020172 query is relevant, but it still doesn't help me.

I must be doing something wrong. How can I make sure the full UPDATE query gets logged?

Comment: Do you now if that `SELECT` was done before the missing `UPDATE`?  Or after?

Comment: I don't know. I do find it interesting that the query before and after that select statement has the same PID

Comment: The "Process ID" identifies the connection.  Typically, many queries are performed in a single connection.

Comment: Good to know, I assumed the two lines must be closely related but maybe that's not the case